# Get increment value from input area in a for-loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, input, increment

I have done this working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mitma/aLfx7ejh/):

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="input_container">
        <label for="increment_t">Set t-increment value (default 0.1):</label>
        <input id="increment_t" type="number" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="0.1" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="generator_container">
        <a id="downloadlink" download="outfile.txt">Download</a>
        <button id="create_link">Export output</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 10px 10px; /* (top-bottom) (left-right) */
    z-index: 1;
}
#input_container {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#increment_t {
    max-width: 50px;
}
#generator_container {
    display: block;
    float: right;
}
#downloadlink {
    display: none;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
#create_link {
    float: right;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
(function () {
    var t_values;
    var t_values_list = [];
    for ( var t=0; t<=1; t+=0.1 ){
        t_values = t.toFixed(1);
        t_values_list.push(t_values);
    }    

    var textFile = null;
    makeTextFile = function (text) {
        var data = new Blob([text], {type: 'text/plain'});

        if (textFile !== null) {
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(textFile);
        }

        textFile = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);

        return textFile;
    };

    var create_link = document.getElementById('create_link');

    create_link.addEventListener('click', function () {
        alert(t_values_list);
        var link = document.getElementById('downloadlink');
        link.href = makeTextFile(t_values_list.join('\n'));
        link.style.display = 'inline-block';
    }, false);
})();
```

but I want to set the *increment value* for the "t" variable (i.e. *0.1*, in the *for-loop*) taking it from the input area. I tried in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/mitma/459h1j6x/4/) way:

**JavaScript**

```
(function () {
    var t_values;
    var t_values_list = [];
    alert(document.getElementById("increment_t").value); // test to get the t value, to use it in the following loop for
    for ( var t=0, increment_t=document.getElementById("increment_t").value; t<=1; t+=increment_t ){
        t_values = t.toFixed(1);
        t_values_list.push(t_values);
    }    

    var textFile = null;
    makeTextFile = function (text) {
        var data = new Blob([text], {type: 'text/plain'});

        if (textFile !== null) {
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(textFile);
        }

        textFile = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);

        return textFile;
    };

    var create_link = document.getElementById('create_link');

    create_link.addEventListener('click', function () {
        alert(t_values_list);
        var link = document.getElementById('downloadlink');
        link.href = makeTextFile(t_values_list.join('\n'));
        link.style.display = 'inline-block';
    }, false);
})();
```

but It doesn't work. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you getting numbers from somewhere else in javascript...**always** parse them. **parseInt(..., 10)** or in your example: **parseFloat**

Comment: Perfect :)... Many thanks! Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mitma/459h1j6x/5/